# Nesting box cleaning

Tags: birds

I was building a nesting box to [encourage birds in my garden](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1782/how-can-i-naturally-encourage-birds-into-my-garden). It worked, a week ago a family of *Blue Tit* moved out after a stressful time. I'm curious so I got up to box to check what they left. I was surprised by the size of the nest and would like to know:

1) To raise the chance of having another couple doing their business inside this year do I need to clean or better leave as much as possible of the material inside and do the cleaning in late autumn (or early spring next year)?

2) As it can be seen below 3 eggs "didn't work". Is that normal for blue tits or this an indicator for a buggy box or place?

3) I hope GL.SE is the right place for asking this question?!

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is off topic. I would try your local ornithological group, or the RSPB (I'm assuming you're in the UK)

Comment: Sigh... before the close votes started, I almost joked that you should move this to blue.tit.nesting.box.stackexchange.com.  Anyway... yes, you should clean out the box if convenient.  If you want to leave the old nest nearby, material from it may be recycled.  I don't think anyone can reliably say why the eggs didn't hatch - too many possibilities.  It's not normal, if I understand what you mean by the word.

Comment: Thanks, @EdStaub. Good idea with that recycling of old material by putting it close to the box.

Comment: @winwaed, sorry for posting this question. As my 3rd sub-question indicates I wasn't sure myself. However, if I'd think that the simple discussion of putting nesting boxes into a garden could go as "landscaping" but a discussion about their size and the diameter of the whole would be off-topic, what would you say? Does the FAQ needs to be even clearer to avoid such OT-questions in the future?